# Racket - read from stdin until new line

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to read from stdin element by element but I don't know how to stop when I insert a new line.
Here is my code:

```
(define readNext
  (lambda (tmp)
    (let ([a (read)])
     (if (equal? a ??????)
       tmp
       (readNext (cons (read) tmp))))))
```

Comment: You can use `(read-line)` to read a single line, then feed that to `read` using `open-input-string`. I don’t think it’s possible to configure `read` to not consume newlines like any other kind of whitespace, though maybe it would be doable using a readtable? I’m not sure if that would actually work or not.

Comment: It will only read the first element.

Comment: acctually it could work

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works as I expected.

```
(define a (open-input-string (read-line)))
 (define readNext
  (lambda (tmp)
   (let ([b (read a)])
     (if (equal? b eof)
       tmp
       (readNext (append tmp (list b)))))))

(readNext '())
```

EDIT: It won't stop on `newline` but for `eof`

Answer (score 0):

The function `read` will read an entire datum.
If you want to read characters until you hit newline,
you will have to one character at a time.

The newline character is written `#\newline`.

Something like this:

```
#lang racket
(define read-a-line-as-list
  (lambda ()
    (let ([c (read-char)])
     (if (equal? c #\newline)
         '()
         (cons c (read-a-line-as-list))))))

(define read-a-line
  (lambda ()
    (list->string (read-a-line-as-list))))

(read-a-line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it like this

```
(for ((_ (in-naturals)))
   (define l (read-line))
   #:break (eof-object? l)
   (displayln l))
```

might not be the most idiomatic, but it works. Use `for/list` or similar to do something more useful with the lines being read.